# Could I power a corded device with batteries?

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, camera

I have a camera which requires a power supply of 12 V. I want to use it away from a power point, so I thought I could hook up an 8-battery AA holder to it. Would this be possible? See images attached.

The power supply that came with it:

[image: The power supply that came with it]

Where it plugs in:

[image: Where it plugs in]

The whole camera:

[image: The whole camera]

The battery holder I plan to use:

[image: The battery holder I plan to use]

Comment: Maybe better to use 10 NiMH batteries (1.2 V each).

Comment: I had to do something similar and used a standard USB power bank (those backup battery things people use for their cell phones) along with one of these:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B074R7FDCR .  You might need an sizing adapter for the DC plug to match it to the camera's DC jack.

Comment: Perfectly doable, but because of the capacity and fairly constant 12 V you need during battery discharge, I would start googling *power bank with 12 volt output*. There are plenty around, but not as cheap as your proposed solution.

Comment: There is on market a lot of rechargable li ion bateries with 1.5V output and different form factor. Bigger capacity.

Comment: If the device actually needs the 1A output for any length of time, AA batteries may have difficulty. They nominally can take 2A peak, but sustaining 1A will limit their lifetime.

Comment: @SteKulov horrible. Those use pretty bad step up circuits and low current capabilities. A better option is a QC/PD power bank with a PD trigger module. The Power bank will step it up and should have the right amperage delivering capacity.

Comment: @Passerby  Ah, gotcha.  That's a much better idea.  Thank you for putting me in my place.

Answer (score 12):

It will probably work for at least a little while. The issue is that a "1.5V" alkaline battery starts at around 1.6V and drops down to 1V over the life of the cell. The camera can probably tolerate 12.8V, but as the batteries discharge it will stop working at some point.

Because it's not designed to be be battery powered, this point might be 11V for example. If that were the case the camera would stop working when there was still 50% of the energy left in the batteries (just making up numbers here to illustrate the point).

A better solution is to use a switching regulator to produce exactly 12V, independent of the battery charge level. You can use a buck converter, which will require more than 12V input, or a boost converter, where the input must be less than 12V. You generally don't want to cross the output voltage because that would require a more complicated buck/boost regulator. So stay completely under, or completely over it for simplicity.

Comment: Using a switching regulator also allows you much bigger flexibility in choosing the type of battery. You could use 16 AA's (that's probably too many :) or a few lantern batteries in series, or a lipo or lifepo4 battery, or a SLA battery (which is like a small car battery, coming in many different sizes). If using a decent-sized li* or SLA battery it is important to use a fuse and beware of short circuits, because those batteries have the power to melt things.

Answer (score 5):

Use whatever batteries you want. Use a SEPIC converter, it is a buck boost combined and set the output to what you want. It will automatically switch modes depending on the input output delta. Nice thing you can switch battery types and not have to adjust anything. The ones I use were china specials that worked from about 4V to 24 volt without any problems. You need to be careful as some batteries if over discharged are destroyed.

Comment: Using a small battery that could not deliver the needed current for at least 20 minutes is the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you can run the camera directly off batteries very much depends on the design of the camera. Unfortunately there may be no way to find out except trying it. Something with a nominally "12V" input is likely to be less problematic than something with a nominally "5V" input because 12V is unlikely to be used to power logic directly, nor used to power logic via a "low dropout" regulator design. The input to output differential of a regulator starting from 12V and used to run logic will normally be at least 7V which leaves plenty of scope for undervoltage.

Modern power bricks generally provide a well-regulated supply, probablly better than 5% in practice. Alkaline batteries provide a voltage that starts slightly above nominal and drops significantly through the discharge cycle.

NiMH batteries are more stable, but have a lower initial voltage, meaning you need more of them. This creates a risk of overvoltage is someone swaps those NiMH batteries for alkaline ones.

Comment: most computer chips ("logic") don't run on 5V any more. Otherwise, yes, this is true.

Comment: No, but a lot of stuff still runs on 3.3V. Depending on the dropout voltage spec of the 3.3V regulator there may not be much scope for the 5V rail to drop before it starts affecting the 3.3V rail.

Comment: For example if someone uses a 3.3V regulator with a 1.5V dropout, that only allows 0.2V of drop before the 3.3V regulator enters dropout.

Comment: Camera's IR LEDs might be designed to run at 12 V.

Comment: Yeah, that might be an issue, you might quickly lose brigtness in said LEDs as the voltage drops past some threshold level.

Answer (score 1):

As an off the shelf option (ie not adding a voltage regulator into the mix), a box holding 10 batteries filled with NiMH rechargeable batteries would work much better.  They stay close to 1.2V over their entire discharge cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the power supply is 12v 1A, the draw is likely a lot less, unless it has IR LEDs on it, and even then, only when its dark. The supply is common and probably just cheap in bulk.

I might look into a small SLA battery like the kind you find in UPS backup units.

They are quite powerful, deep cycle, and locally, you can probably find them for $15 or so (place that sells ATVs, lawnmowers, etc). You could buy 2 of them, and a charger and just swap them out on a regular schedule. Might need a small voltage regulator to keep it right at 12V, but I'd get a couple barrel plug sockets and swapping the battery would take like 5 seconds.

[https://www.amazon.com/Weize-Sealed-Cycle-Rechargeable-Battery/dp/B07QPYFBW6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QPYFBW6)

Comment: Note: A fully-charged "12V" lead-acid battery is 13.2V (10% higher)

Comment: *"unless it has IR LEDs on it"* From the picture, it looks like it does.

Answer (score 1):

*Could I power a corded device with batteries?*

Yes. I did this with a set of desktop computer speakers. I started with a 9v battery, but it didn't last and was expensive. I ended up with a bank of 6 AA batteries. I used it for mobile listening for years.

It worked really well and had long battery life, but that's a completely different power load/requirement than a camera. The speakers would work even at low battery levels so I could use batteries other devices had drained below their power requirements.

*I have a camera...*

Like other answers state, it depends on how the camera is designed.

If it's designed like an Arduino where the actual range of voltage input is something like 5v-12v, then it could work well and you'd have plenty of recording time. It may be that the "12v 1A" label is just a voltage and amperage that the manufacturer decided they wanted to use as a power source and stamping a range on the device would only confuse end users.

However, it may be that the camera really does need 12v at 1 amp. You won't know until you try. Since you are using a standard power plug and not modifying the camera, your test shouldn't significantly damage the device.

Feel free to post the results of your test back as an Answer. Other people might be looking to do the same thing and your real life test would be the answer for this specific model of camera. Self answers are usually welcome, as long as they actually answer the question with relevant details. Many times, that's more useful than people guessing, like this and the other current answers are doing.

Answer (score 0):

And for a completely different solution:

https://www.amazon.com/portable-120-volt-power-supply/s?k=portable+120+volt+power+supply

There are power banks that put out line power and would then work through your power supply.  Heavier and more expensive but if that thing is really drawing anything like 1A (it might just be a commodity power supply) you're not going to get much life with your approach.